# Python OpenCV--MAC WebCam doesn't close

Tags: python, opencv, imutils

I am running a face recognition code and my issue is that after running the code, my webcam doesn't close. The green light is still activated and in order to close it, i have to close my computer in order to have the cam ok.
What do you suggest, why is like that?

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import argparse, imutils, time, cv2, os, sys
import time
import smtplib, os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email import encoders


   detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
# vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
vs = VideoStream
vs(src=0).start()
# time.sleep(2.0)
total = 0

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    orig = frame.copy()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
    rects = detector.detectMultiScale(
        cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), scaleFactor=1.1, 
        minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30))
    for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        if rects is not None and total <5:
            p="/Users/Desktop/atentie/mail/"+str(total)+".png"
            cv2.imwrite(p, orig)
            total+=1

    break   

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs(src=0).stop()
time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VideoStream` from `imutils` library is a class object, so when you assign it to `vs` you ought to treat it like one.

Here is the fix:

```
#--- import libraries ---
from imutils.video import VideoStream

vs = VideoStream
#--- start the video stream ---
vs(src=0).start()

#--
# rest of your program 
#--

#--- stop the video stream ---
vs(src=0).stop()
```

Comment: Thank you Luke! still doesn't do the trick and the camera doesn't close. the green light is still open.

Comment: @Cohen silly me I made a mistake. You are supposed to add `vs = VideoStream` before starting the stream. Check the update

Comment: i did, i did! i got it, but still, it doesn't close...dunno what to do.

Comment: this wouldn't change anything, you are copying the class, and using it later, forgetting affecting the instantiation.

Comment: @Cohen You are doing it wrong. Please look closely it is `vs = VideoStream` not `vs = VideoStream(src=0)`. I tried it and it works, that is why I am suggesting it.

Comment: I've changed it because i get this error odule>
    frame = vs.read()
TypeError: read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @Cohen I'm sorry but it works fine for me. Can you share the updated code again?

Comment: @Cohen I tried the same on another system and the camera actually turns off. I still don't understand why it doesn't work for you :(

Comment: Me neither. I am on a mac.

Comment: @Cohen The two systems that I tried on are Windows 8 and 10

Comment: am on Mac so Unix environment. 10x

Comment: Yes. I changed the code. Somehow there was a loop that didnt want to break so i had to use raise Syserror or something like this. Thanks for help tough!